# How prevent href title attribute show over transparent Form?

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-10.3-rio

I have these two code that makes a Form transparent.

```
 Form1.AlphaBlend := True;
 SetWindowLong(Form1.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(Form1.Handle,GWL_EXSTYLE) or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT or WS_EX_LAYERED);
```

---

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
     protected
      procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override; 
  end;

// AlphaBlend := True;
  procedure TForm1.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
  begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_TOPMOST or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
  Params.ExStyle := WS_EX_TRANSPARENT or WS_EX_TOPMOST;
  end;
```

When mouse is over a link with a *title* attribute, this appear **over** transparent Form. How prevent this behavior?

[image]

Comment: If you don't want it displayed then perhaps remove the title attribute

Comment: @RohitGupta, i'm searching a solution in Delphi.

Comment: FWIW, your CreateParams makes no sense. You first take the existing `ExStyle` and add  `WS_EX_TOPMOST or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` to it, and then immediately throw that away to replace it with ignoring the existing `ExStyle` and just setting it to `WS_EX_TOPMOST or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`. You should be doing one or the other, not both, and the end result you're getting is only the final line in `CreateParams`. IOW, the first line that sets `Params.ExStyle` can be removed entirely, as it does absolutely nothing.

Comment: This is the solution or only a lateral note?

Comment: Note: You do not need to call `SetWindowLong()` (and FYI, you should be using the `...Ptr` version in order to support 64bit builds), or override `CreateParams()`, to enable the `WS_EX_LAYERED` style. Enabling the `AlphaBlend` (or `Transparent`) property will handle that internally for you. And, you can set the form's `FormStyle` to `fsStayOnTop` to enable the `WS_EX_TOPMOST` style. The only style you should be managing manually in this case is `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`

Comment: Wait are you trying to get rid of white square with LVTF text that is just bellow mouse cursor in the attached image? If so do note that this is a hint window. Hint window always  shows even above topmost form.So how to get rid of this. Well disable showing of hints for specific forms or components. Normally you control showing of hints with [ShowHint](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.ShowHint) property for specific form or component.

Comment: @SilverWarior, this hint is of html (site of web), not of my delphi Form.

Comment: In that case this becomes a lot more difficult. Why? There are multiple ways that web page can show such Tooltip. So finding a reliable solution that will disable all might be even impossible. There are numerous threads about this here on Stack Overflow.